# C# anyway to automatically break after a button click

Tags: c#, winforms

If I have a project and I do not how design corresponds to the code is there a way to make the debugger break every time I press any button so I can quickly navigate to the right place in the code or am I asking for too much here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make a call to `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` to tell any attached debuggers to break at that line.

If none are attached, Windows will try to launch any registered debuggers.  If not are registered, you'll get an exception/crash of the application.  So, don't leave it in the code in production :)

e.g. (as per icemanind's comment)

```
#if DEBUG
    Debugger.Break();
#endif
```

If you want to break on a click of *any* button, it gets a bit tricky.  The easiest thing is to write a `Button` wrapper class and override `OnClick` and put your Break call in there.  For example:

```
public class ButtonWedge : Button
{
    protected override void OnClick(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```

Once you add that class you can drag and drop it on the design surface.  But, if you've already got code, you can edit the designer.cs file and replace `System.Windows.Forms.Button` with `ButtonWedge`.

Once in `OnClick`, you can see where the `Click` event will go by looking at the base classes `Events` array with the `Control.EventClick` key.  That will contain a multicast delegate that you can look at the `Method` and `Target` properties to find out what has subscribed to this `Click` event.  In other words, the name of the click handler at runtime will be:

```
string handlerName = base.Events[Control.EventClick].Target.GetType().FullName + '.'
   + base.Events[Control.EventClick].Method.Name;
```

It doesn't really put a break point in a particular `Click` event but lets you know what's going on and where...

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, it might be wise to surround the `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` around `#if DEBUG` and `#endif` directives, that way you won't have to keep removing and adding them for debugging/release versions

Comment: You can also surround the suggested code with if(Debugger.IsAttached) {...} to limit the behavior to only when the debugger is attached (except for a tiny race condition if the debugger gets detached after the IsAttached check and before Break() is called).

Comment: Where would I put the System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() if I do not know the events that are triggered by the button if I don't know the buttons name?

Comment: @NickolayKondratyev It get's a bit tricky, I've added some detail to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant a button on the program in the project then use Peter's answer. If you were asking can you make a button on the keyboard or mouse cause execution to break or pause, you can press Ctrl+Alt+Pause.

Answer (score 1):

Why you cannot just DoubleClick on the button in design mode. Its open in  code right on the function that handles a click event.